# Nginx SSL config returns too many redirects, but regular http version is fine

Tags: nginx, ssl, cloudflare

I have recently tried to add SSL termination to my NGINX server configuration. The regular http reverse proxy/load balance version is working fine. Unfortunately, the current config is returning "too many redirects" in the browser.
Notes of relevance: This NGINX server is receiving traffic from Cloudflare's Full SSL and then goes on to pass traffic (over plain http) to another Nginx server in front of a dockerized [discourse](https://www.discourse.org/) instance.
Just wondering if anything is wrong here considering Cloudflare and discourse, or if something is configured incorrectly somewhere else. Any help is appreciated!

```
upstream discourse {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    # Enforce the use of HTTPS and redirect www sub to root
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example-error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/example.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ etc..."

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://discourse;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly; make sure you're using Full SSL in CloudFlare, not Flexible SSL. Then the next step is to make sure that any redirects on your origin use the X-Forwarded-For instead of the SSL environment variable; remember your origin web servers will see the connection in plain text after you use SSL termination.

Answer (score 0):

You probably configured cloudflare to proxy to 80/HTTP port of your nginx web server. So, it jumps to first server block of your config and generates redirect to https://...
To fix this, configure cloudflare to use 443/HTTPS of your nginx web server as backend.

Comment: You answer was helpful too! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Seems that in addition to selecting Full SSL, a Page Rule of "Always use https" helped.